# Microk8s keeps evicting pods

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes

I have just [installed Microk8s through Ubuntu directly](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/install-a-local-kubernetes-with-microk8s#0).

Interestingly, when I create a deployment, the pods appear to get evicted. Here's the output. What could be causing this? Let me know if you need any additional debugging info.

```
user@mindy:~$ microk8s.kubectl get all
NAME                                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-2dtrg     0/1     Evicted   0          3h41m
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-2glqz     0/1     Evicted   0          9h
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-2w6s9     0/1     Evicted   0          14h
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-4brht     0/1     Evicted   0          7h56m
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-4fwgt     0/1     Evicted   0          8h
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-5bnvh     0/1     Evicted   0          10h
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-5knws     0/1     Evicted   0          11h
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-5mcfp     0/1     Evicted   0          11h
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-5vcts     0/1     Evicted   0          7h48m
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-6lq2p     0/1     Evicted   0          5h5m
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-6qtxf     0/1     Evicted   0          11h
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-6t24h     0/1     Evicted   0          71m
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-6tnqh     0/1     Evicted   0          15h
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-6wqs4     0/1     Evicted   0          8h
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-747ht     0/1     Evicted   0          3h17m
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-7qdx7     0/1     Evicted   0          6h15m
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-7tpr2     0/1     Evicted   0          14h
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-7x5kg     0/1     Evicted   0          3h9m
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-82k4v     0/1     Evicted   0          10h
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-85cx6     0/1     Evicted   0          7h1m
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-88t8q     0/1     Evicted   0          106m
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-8j92p     0/1     Evicted   0          3h
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-8p5hk     0/1     Evicted   0          63m
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-8qld2     0/1     Evicted   0          8h
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-8tjf5     0/1     Evicted   0          3h25m
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-9jgwn     0/1     Evicted   0          12h
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-9qnnx     0/1     Evicted   0          15h
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-b6k9z     0/1     Evicted   0          6h30m
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-b7rn7     0/1     Evicted   0          13h
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-b8rgt     0/1     Evicted   0          39m
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-b944r     0/1     Evicted   0          8h
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-bbqqz     0/1     Evicted   0          5h20m
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-bznp7     0/1     Pending   0          6m26s
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-cc4jj     0/1     Evicted   0          5h28m
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-cpth9     0/1     Evicted   0          7h17m
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-crwlk     0/1     Evicted   0          14h
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-d5bzh     0/1     Evicted   0          10h
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-dfw4l     0/1     Evicted   0          9h
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-dq47n     0/1     Evicted   0          7h9m
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-dw6ph     0/1     Evicted   0          80m
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-f4jxj     0/1     Evicted   0          15h
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-f62nt     0/1     Evicted   0          8h
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-f7r45     0/1     Evicted   0          8h
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-fh9mw     0/1     Evicted   0          9h
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-gm9kg     0/1     Evicted   0          14h
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-gpmwx     0/1     Evicted   0          6h46m
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-h7xpc     0/1     Evicted   0          5h36m
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-hgxln     0/1     Evicted   0          138m
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-hz4ks     0/1     Evicted   0          15h
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-j78fh     0/1     Evicted   0          10h
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-jjtzr     0/1     Evicted   0          4h38m
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-jkjdw     0/1     Evicted   0          4h57m
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-jp8qq     0/1     Evicted   0          12h
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-jqjcc     0/1     Evicted   0          10h
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-jrdkn     0/1     Evicted   0          9h
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-jzg89     0/1     Evicted   0          6h53m
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-k4dwn     0/1     Evicted   0          89m
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-k57l2     0/1     Evicted   0          47m
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-kb9rq     0/1     Evicted   0          10h
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-kcgxr     0/1     Evicted   0          8h
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-kcnhs     0/1     Evicted   0          56m
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-kl966     0/1     Evicted   0          10h
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-ksr7r     0/1     Evicted   0          10h
pod/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66-kwd6h     0/1     Evicted   0          10h

pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-jsvqd                0/1     Evicted   0          97m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-jth6p                0/1     Evicted   0          81m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-jzbqd                0/1     Evicted   0          3h57m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-k95tr                0/1     Evicted   0          14h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-kd8r5                0/1     Evicted   0          90m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-kdd5l                0/1     Evicted   0          7h9m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-khlsv                0/1     Evicted   0          4h57m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-kqpnc                0/1     Evicted   0          14h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-kv7gt                0/1     Evicted   0          6h30m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-kwsfj                0/1     Evicted   0          6h38m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-kxth8                0/1     Evicted   0          4h14m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-l58jh                0/1     Evicted   0          7h25m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-l5mf9                0/1     Evicted   0          9h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-l6l79                0/1     Evicted   0          11h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-l9d6z                0/1     Evicted   0          14h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-l9pdx                0/1     Evicted   0          173m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-l9r2c                0/1     Evicted   0          6h8m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-lbsxq                0/1     Evicted   0          10h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-lchjq                0/1     Evicted   0          4h30m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-ld75m                0/1     Evicted   0          9h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-ldncj                0/1     Evicted   0          7h56m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-lf289                0/1     Evicted   0          5h20m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-lnrsr                0/1     Evicted   0          14h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-lq42n                0/1     Evicted   0          11h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-lqgps                0/1     Evicted   0          6h15m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-lqhtb                0/1     Evicted   0          47m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-lvzk5                0/1     Evicted   0          9h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-m2mth                0/1     Evicted   0          148m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-m4rsq                0/1     Evicted   0          6h53m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-m6sv8                0/1     Evicted   0          10h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-m8zmw                0/1     Evicted   0          10h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-mg7gg                0/1     Evicted   0          4h38m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-mhqr5                0/1     Evicted   0          13h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-mj4tv                0/1     Evicted   0          10h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-mkkst                0/1     Evicted   0          12h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-mlhnx                0/1     Evicted   0          89m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-mmcxq                0/1     Evicted   0          10h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-mq6vp                0/1     Evicted   0          156m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-mrkz6                0/1     Evicted   0          12h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-mtftn                0/1     Evicted   0          3h34m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-mwt9n                0/1     Evicted   0          15h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-mzlvt                0/1     Evicted   0          122m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-n4tlj                0/1     Evicted   0          11h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-n7ctx                0/1     Evicted   0          9h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-n8kc8                0/1     Evicted   0          12h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-n8xmv                0/1     Evicted   0          14h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-n9z5r                0/1     Evicted   0          4h14m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-nbcvx                0/1     Evicted   0          56m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-ncv5z                0/1     Evicted   0          5h28m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-nf2bs                0/1     Evicted   0          4h46m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-nf58f                0/1     Evicted   0          14h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-ngnhj                0/1     Evicted   0          14h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-npchs                0/1     Evicted   0          14h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-nz8kj                0/1     Evicted   0          23m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-p67r4                0/1     Evicted   0          7h2m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-p97rk                0/1     Evicted   0          12h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-pbtb5                0/1     Evicted   0          13h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-phb65                0/1     Evicted   0          12h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-phqs9                0/1     Evicted   0          8h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-phtl9                0/1     Evicted   0          9h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-pqwtc                0/1     Evicted   0          3h25m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-pvgc6                0/1     Evicted   0          5h36m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-pwhk2                0/1     Evicted   0          10h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-pws95                0/1     Evicted   0          15m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-q2p84                0/1     Pending   0          7m2s
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-q4f9w                0/1     Evicted   0          7h33m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-q4p65                0/1     Evicted   0          9h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-q4r5d                0/1     Evicted   0          15h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-q526b                0/1     Evicted   0          12h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-q5k76                0/1     Evicted   0          12h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-q9gn4                0/1     Evicted   0          14h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-qgthj                0/1     Evicted   0          4h14m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-qkggg                0/1     Evicted   0          12h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-qvsd5                0/1     Evicted   0          139m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-qwwn8                0/1     Evicted   0          14h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-qz79c                0/1     Evicted   0          156m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-qzbb8                0/1     Evicted   0          12h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-qzc67                0/1     Evicted   0          4h46m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-qzwl8                0/1     Evicted   0          12h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-r2mml                0/1     Evicted   0          12h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-r6h7v                0/1     Evicted   0          14h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-r86bs                0/1     Evicted   0          10h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-r8wlf                0/1     Evicted   0          12h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-r9lc8                0/1     Evicted   0          8h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-rkn6c                0/1     Evicted   0          6h7m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-rnb75                0/1     Evicted   0          14h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-rnsxn                0/1     Evicted   0          4h14m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-rp9rb                0/1     Evicted   0          11h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-rrkt2                0/1     Evicted   0          11h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-rs42l                0/1     Evicted   0          9h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-rszcb                0/1     Evicted   0          9h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-rwcgb                0/1     Evicted   0          14h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-rwvtf                0/1     Evicted   0          12h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-rxlq2                0/1     Evicted   0          10h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-rxwnz                0/1     Evicted   0          10h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-rz627                0/1     Evicted   0          105m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-s2kxf                0/1     Evicted   0          12h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-s2w2m                0/1     Evicted   0          3h34m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-s48w5                0/1     Evicted   0          13h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-s5pw7                0/1     Evicted   0          11h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-s89vs                0/1     Evicted   0          7h40m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-sb8wv                0/1     Evicted   0          7h25m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-sg5fs                0/1     Evicted   0          31m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-shgpg                0/1     Evicted   0          106m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-sj4j4                0/1     Evicted   0          12h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-sk7br                0/1     Evicted   0          9h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-skfgt                0/1     Evicted   0          10h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-sqdg8                0/1     Evicted   0          12h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-sqjdh                0/1     Evicted   0          14h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-srbj5                0/1     Evicted   0          10h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-ss4sf                0/1     Evicted   0          10h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-ssh9j                0/1     Evicted   0          7h2m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-stcp6                0/1     Evicted   0          6h46m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-svm5p                0/1     Evicted   0          10h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-sz4gk                0/1     Evicted   0          4h22m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-t249v                0/1     Evicted   0          138m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-t572g                0/1     Evicted   0          39m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-t89rz                0/1     Evicted   0          7h2m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-t9dkp                0/1     Evicted   0          3h1m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-tdrt9                0/1     Evicted   0          9h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-tfx5v                0/1     Evicted   0          9h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-tjcn9                0/1     Evicted   0          7h17m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-tlq42                0/1     Evicted   0          13h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-tnkh4                0/1     Evicted   0          12h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-tqqlc                0/1     Evicted   0          6h30m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-trdm9                0/1     Evicted   0          11h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-tv56m                0/1     Pending   0          6m59s
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-tzdcc                0/1     Evicted   0          14h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-v28mf                0/1     Evicted   0          14h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-v5j9g                0/1     Evicted   0          12h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-v6w8q                0/1     Evicted   0          5h36m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-v76vs                0/1     Evicted   0          7h33m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-vbf7s                0/1     Evicted   0          13h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-vdtp8                0/1     Evicted   0          11h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-vdzz4                0/1     Evicted   0          12h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-vnnr5                0/1     Evicted   0          6h15m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-vnxfq                0/1     Evicted   0          15h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-vrzqx                0/1     Evicted   0          12h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-vszg5                0/1     Evicted   0          4h46m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-vvdmv                0/1     Evicted   0          14h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-vx869                0/1     Evicted   0          9h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-vxc2n                0/1     Evicted   0          10h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-vzk2c                0/1     Evicted   0          10h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-vznvs                0/1     Evicted   0          11h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-vzztp                0/1     Evicted   0          9h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-w5p7f                0/1     Evicted   0          12h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-w5shv                0/1     Evicted   0          9h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-w7d8l                0/1     Evicted   0          10h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-w8bwx                0/1     Evicted   0          122m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-wb6zs                0/1     Evicted   0          11h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-wdhvs                0/1     Evicted   0          7h48m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-wftx8                0/1     Evicted   0          15h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-wgc8p                0/1     Evicted   0          5h52m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-wgd7v                0/1     Evicted   0          10h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-wjsns                0/1     Evicted   0          11h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-wpjc4                0/1     Evicted   0          11h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-wwb2l                0/1     Evicted   0          13h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-x4cfr                0/1     Evicted   0          31m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-x4dzn                0/1     Evicted   0          10h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-x4hdh                0/1     Evicted   0          14h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-x96b2                0/1     Evicted   0          130m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-xbc4r                0/1     Evicted   0          4h38m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-xbp5c                0/1     Evicted   0          14h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-xc42w                0/1     Evicted   0          13h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-xc9xr                0/1     Evicted   0          12h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-xd8h6                0/1     Evicted   0          114m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-xg7hg                0/1     Evicted   0          6h23m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-xh7tg                0/1     Evicted   0          14h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-xj8vl                0/1     Evicted   0          8h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-xp8zg                0/1     Evicted   0          8h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-xp9ww                0/1     Evicted   0          4h46m
NAME                                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-xrds9                0/1     Evicted   0          10h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-xs5fx                0/1     Evicted   0          14h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-xssg8                0/1     Evicted   0          9h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-xtp7p                0/1     Evicted   0          10h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-xtqsn                0/1     Evicted   0          14h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-xxcfv                0/1     Evicted   0          6h38m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-xzmvj                0/1     Evicted   0          14h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-xzztc                0/1     Evicted   0          14h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-z2w5h                0/1     Evicted   0          11h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-z47tk                0/1     Evicted   0          165m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-z6x2j                0/1     Evicted   0          14h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-z78tz                0/1     Evicted   0          7h17m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-zb8xl                0/1     Evicted   0          8h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-zqsph                0/1     Evicted   0          3h9m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-ztmhf                0/1     Evicted   0          165m
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-zw55z                0/1     Evicted   0          10h
pod/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98-zz2dx                0/1     Evicted   0          9h

NAME                           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/default-http-backend   ClusterIP   10.152.183.80   <none>        80/TCP    15h
service/kubernetes             ClusterIP   10.152.183.1    <none>        443/TCP   15h

NAME                                               DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR   AGE
daemonset.apps/nginx-ingress-microk8s-controller   1         1         0       1            0           <none>          15h

NAME                                   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/default-http-backend   0/1     1            0           15h
deployment.apps/tjf-nginx              0/2     2            0           15h

NAME                                              DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/default-http-backend-5769f6bc66   1         1         0       15h
replicaset.apps/tjf-nginx-5d995fff98              2         2         0       15h
user@mindy:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to troubleshoot kubernetes, but the most basic one is to `describe` a failed/evicted pod.

Run `microk8s.kubectl describe pod [name-of-eviced-pod]`. In the last part of the output you'll see life `Events` of the pod, where eviction reason will be mentioned.

You can try any ways of troubleshooting described here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-application/ All commands described in this article will work for you when you add `microk8s.` in front of `kubectl`.

If the issue lies in microk8s deployment itself then you should go with `microk8s.inspect`, as described [here](https://microk8s.io/docs/):

> This command performs a set of tests against MicroK8s and collects
>   traces and logs in a report tarball.